# Expression inside switch case statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

I'm trying to create a switch statement but I can't seem to be able to use an expression that gets evaluated (rather than a set string/integer). I can easily do this with if statements but case should hopefully be faster.

**I'm trying the following**

```
function reward(amount) {
    var $reward = $("#reward");
    switch (amount) {
        case (amount >= 7500 && amount < 10000):
            $reward.text("Play Station 3");
            break;
        case (amount >= 10000 && amount < 15000):
            $reward.text("XBOX 360");
            break;
        case (amount >= 15000):
            $reward.text("iMac");
            break;
        default:
            $reward.text("No reward");
            break;
    }
}
```

Am i missing something obvious or is this not possible? Google hasn't been friendly in this case.

**Any help/pointers appreciated**

**M**

Answer (score 169, accepted):

`amount` is a number, but the expressions in the `case` clauses only evaluate to booleans; the values will never match.

You could always do

```js
switch (true) {
  case (amount >= 7500 && amount < 10000):
    // Code
    break;
  case (amount >= 10000 && amount < 15000):
    // Code
    break;
  // etc.
}
```

It works because the value being matched is now the boolean `true`, so the code under the first `case` clause with an expression that evaluates to `true` will be executed.

It’s kinda “tricky”, I guess, but I see nothing wrong with using it. A simple `if`–`else` statement would probably be more concise, and you’d not have to worry about accidental fall-through. But there it is anyway.

Comment: This is better as an answer than Daniels "answer". With a slight warning: all the expressions before the one leading to case true, will be evaluated too. be careful.

Comment: Yes, this works because you can always think of a switch function like a jump table, it only has to match and retrieve a value. This is unlike if/else statements because all if's need to actually be evaluated.  Above you are asking your switch to evaluate vs match.  That is why switch cases are faster.

Comment: @Vontei - With an if/else if/else structure they're not *all* evaluated, they're evaluated in turn only until a particular condition is true, which is the same thing that happens with evaluating `case` expressions.

Answer (score 16):

@MooGoo's [`switch (true)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3463944/1028230) will give you a [`Weird condition` error in jsLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658601/is-a-reversed-switch-statement-acceptable-javascript), so let's get a little more creative in case that's an issue, and, I think, increase readability a touch.

So we're not evaluating if each `case` is `true` or `false`; we're comparing if that `case`'s value is equal to our `switch` term.  So let's take advantage of that by throwing a shorthand `if` into our `case` statement and **return our original switch term if the condition's true**.

I'm also including a sort of real world example, where you want to have two "defaults" -- one if your term is outside of your "important" range in the positive direction, and another in case you're in the negative direction.

Key phrase:
`case (x > 0 ? x : null):`

"If my term, `x`, is greater than zero, return `x` so that `x === x` and I take the case branch."

http://jsfiddle.net/rufwork/upGH6/1/

```
/*global document*/
/*jslint evil:true*/
var x = 10;

switch (x) {
    case (x > 0 ? x : null):
        document.write('ha ha ha!  I fooled switch AND jsLint!  Muhahahahaha!');
        break;
    case 0:
        document.write('zero is nothing.');
        break;
    case -1:
        document.write('low');
        break;
    case -2:
        document.write('lower');
        break;
    case -3: 
        document.write('lowest I care about');
        break;
    default: // anything lower than -3.
        document.write('TOO LOW!!!! (unless you cheated and didn\'t use an int)');
}
document.write('<br>done.');
```

---

#### Quick reply [to @Sv443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463833/expression-inside-switch-case-statement/14901106?noredirect=1#comment119961440_14901106):

Do notice that the `default:` switch says, "*unless you cheated and didn't use an int*" and that short circuiting requires `x === x` when you return `x`.

But your point is a useful reminder that `NaN` is the *only* case where short circuiting can't apply.

That is, **`x` must `== x` to short circuit in `switch`** and, as MDN tells us, "[*NaN, and only NaN, will compare unequal to itself*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#examples)" (double *or* triple `=`).

That also means that switching on a `NaN` value (and *only* a `NaN` value) will *always* hit `default` in **ANY** `switch` because you can't match its value.

Here's the full quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#examples):

> NaN compares unequal (via ==, !=, ===, and !==) to any other value -- including to another NaN value. Use [Number.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) or [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to most clearly determine whether a value is NaN. Or perform a self-comparison: NaN, and only NaN, will compare unequal to itself.

You could change the `default` logic to check what you have:

`isNaN(x) ? document.write ('nan') : document.write('TOO LOW!!!! ...)');`

Or you even could go full hipster like MDN suggests (but please don't ;^D):

`x !== x ? document.write ('nan') : document.write('TOO LOW!!!! ...)');`

Comment: This may fool JSLint, but is weirder and harder to read than the thing JSLint was complaining about in the first place. If you've made a conscious decision to use a `switch` with expressions in the cases like the OP wanted and MooGoo explained, then you're not going to worry about that particular JSLint warning.

Comment: @nnnnnn Well, I'd say `switch (true)` is completely antipattern, as the MooGoo is essentially recreating `if... else if... else`. My main point is that the question does make me think of one arguably practical use for ranges in switches -- **if you find yourself in a `switch` paradigm that essentially needs two (+?) defaults**. Neat to learn that you can use an expression in a `case`, return your `switch`'s param value, and force invocation at that statement. But it sounds like you're voting for @Daniel & @FyodorSoikin's "*that's not how switch works*" answers, and I really can't argue that ;)

Comment: Note that this doesn't work when `x = NaN`, since internally JS presumably does an equality check, which is impossible with the `NaN` constant (it'd need to check with `Number.isNaN()` , which it doesn't do)

Comment: @Sv443 Addressed in answer update. In this case `NaN` is literally the exception that proves (well, is the single exception to) the rule.

Comment: Thanks for editing this 8 year old answer :)

Answer (score 10):

That is not how a `switch` block works. The `case` is used to hold a single value that if they are equal to the value on the `switch` line. `if-else` statements will serve you well.

Here is some information about the `switch` block.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: This answer is still wrong: check the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-switch-statement) — both _⟨expr1⟩_ and _⟨expr2⟩_ in `switch(` _⟨expr1⟩_ `){ case` _⟨expr2⟩_ `: break; }` are expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can have expressions in `case` statement which is why your switch is not a syntax error. But you have to understand that the *Case Clause* is compared using === (strict comparison). Once you understand this, that the value must match exactly with the expression value in your `switch(expression)` you can shop around for expressions in js.

Function calls are expressions, so let's try with them:

```
function xbox(amount) { return amount >= 10000 && amount < 15000 && amount; }

function reward(amount) {
  var ps3 = function(amount) { return amount >= 7500 && amount < 10000 && amount; }

  function imac(amount) { return amount >= 15000 && amount; }

  var $reward = $("#reward");
  switch (amount) {
    case ps3(amount):
      $reward.text("Play Station 3");
      break;
    case xbox(amount):
      $reward.text("XBOX 360");
      break;
    case imac(amount):
      $reward.text("iMac");
      break;
    default:
      $reward.text("No reward");
      break;
  }
}
reward(8200)// -> Play Station 3
reward(11000)// -> XBOX 360
reward(20000)// -> iMac
```

As you can see, you can both use function expressions and function definitions. It doesn't matter. Only that the expression in the case clause is an expression to evaluate. Which is the same as you did, only you did not return a value that was the same as the amount but rather a true or false value. In my example I return the exact amount if my condition is true, hence trigger the comparison to match.

Here is your fixed code:

```
function reward(amount) {
    var $reward = $("#reward");
    switch (amount) {
        case (amount >= 7500 && amount < 10000 && amount):
            $reward.text("Play Station 3");
            break;
        case (amount >= 10000 && amount < 15000 && amount):
            $reward.text("XBOX 360");
            break;
        case (amount >= 15000 && amount):
            $reward.text("iMac");
            break;
        default:
            $reward.text("No reward");
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is the specification: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-switch-statement
The link is to es2016 because it's easier to lookup than the old es3 pdf from 1999. But it has always worked like this, but it is a little known fact.

I however doubt that this is faster than `if` statements. If you want your run to run fast, then **do not** touch the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try one of my favorite constructions:

```
function reward(amount) {
    var $reward = $("#reward");
    $reward.text(
        (amount >= 7500 && amount < 10000) ?    "Play Station 3" :
        (amount >= 10000 && amount < 15000)?    "XBOX 360" :
        (amount >= 15000) ?                     "iMac" :
                                                "No reward"
    );
}
```

Comment: Would you still have to check that the amount is under a number if you evaluated them in reverse?

Comment: I guess of course that would stop people with bigger rewards from getter them faster;)

Comment: Nested ternary operators are often feared and discouraged completely.  So it's best to avoid using them unless they're simpler, plainly obvious, and more easily maintained than alternative constructions. I prefer tests that work in any order.  However you choose to write them, simplicity and maintainability trump efficiency here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the switch expression cannot ever equal the case expressions, because the case expression will evaluate to true or false, but the switch expression will be a number.

The solution where the switch expression is set to true works not because true is a constant but because equality with the case expressions is actually possible.

It's not true that you have to specify constants for each case expression.

To back up my answer, refer to Douglas Crockford, Javascript The Good Parts (2008), page 12:

> The switch statement performs a multiway branch. It compares the expression for equality with all the selected cases.... When an exact match is found, the statements of the matching case clause are executed... A case clause contains one or more case expressions. The case expressions need not be constants.

Comment: One could add that the case block evaluation is performed in the order of the source code. From top to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

Ideally switch (as a principle) should evaluate to a single case branch , thereby achieving O(1) performance and (other than fall through cases) the case statements can be reordered in any way without changing the compiler branching strategy.

If expressions are used (assuming the language allows it), then theoretically, it can follow more than branch.

The compiler (other than those which can intelligently say what the developer is trying to do) will not be able to optimize the branching strategy statically and ideally thus losing its effectiveness.

Example:

```
var x = 6, factors = [];

switch(x){

    case (x%2 == 0): factors.push(2);
    break;

    case (x%3 == 0): factors.push(3);
    break;
    ....
 }
```

{Expect comments on poor code}

In the above example, there is no practical way for the compiler to statically optimize, thus gains no performance benefit over if else.

The only part is that, it "may" look cleaner to the developer but could in-effect be cause for disruption in case of additional conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, that's not how `switch` works. You have to specify constants for each `case`, and those constants will be compared to the expression in parentheses (in your case, `amount`). That is how `switch` works, period.

Secondly, switch is not faster than several `if`s

And thirdly, you shouldn't really worry about miniscule performance optimizations when you're dealing with javascript.

Comment: Well, it's always better to worry about performance. It gives you room when you have to do something performance consuming.

Comment: *"You have to specify constants for each case"* - No you don't. Using constants is the most common way to use a `switch`, but you can specify any expression in each `case`, with or without variables or function calls, and the  value is what gets compared.

Comment: The first paragraph is wrong: check the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-switch-statement) — both _⟨expr1⟩_ and _⟨expr2⟩_ in `switch(` _⟨expr1⟩_ `){ case` _⟨expr2⟩_ `: break; }` are expressions. The other two paragraphs are more suitable as a comment, not an answer.