# Is a reversed switch statement acceptable JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, jslint

JSLint is complaining that `(true)` is a `weird condition`. Which is understandable if I wasn't using it on a reversed switch statement. So is JSLint wrong or should I not be using reversed switch statements?

Thanks for any help/enlightenment.

```
switch (true) {
    case (menuLinksLength < 4):
        numberOfColumns = 1;
        break;
    case (menuLinksLength > 3 && menuLinksLength < 7):
        numberOfColumns = 2;
        break;
    case (menuLinksLength > 6 && menuLinksLength < 10):
        numberOfColumns = 3;
        break;
    case (menuLinksLength > 9):
        numberOfColumns = 4;
        break;
    default:
        numberOfColumns = 0;
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you can keep your reversed switch statement and still satisfy the linter if you use `switch(true===true)`. This is not an endorsement of the practice ;)

Comment: `switch(true===true)` doesn't help, as that then causes it to complain about a "Weird relation."

Comment: var theTruth = true;    ----- switch(theTruth) {...}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third edition of the ECMA-262 standard (supported by Firefox 1.0+, Google Chrome 1.0+, MSIE 5.5+ and others) defines that

```
switch (expression) {
    case label1:
        statements1
    .
    .
    .
}
```

executes `statements1` if `(expression)` matches `label1`.

That means that your `switch` statement is perfectly fine.

I tried it out on Firefox, Chrome and IE. None complains...

**Edit:**

Now the guessing part:

JSLint is a code anaylisis tool. When it sees `switch (true)`, it assumes that you don't know what you're doing. *Weird* doesn't mean necessarily *wrong*...

Comment: The reason it's causing me a problem is because the company I work for use it in their build scripts and it fails when JSLint returns 'weird'. I don't know how the errors are classed in JSLint but I guess it might not be it's fault. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No way to disable this check then?

Comment: @Danny: No clue. I've never used JSLint.

Comment: Leaving this question here for anyone who might know: [How to disable the Weird Condition check in JSLint?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24233814)

Answer (score 5):

Personally I wouldn't like seeing reversed `switch` in a code base. It doesn't buy you anything when compared to a plain `if/elseif` block, and its exotic nature can be cause for confusion.

That's also what JSLint is complaining about:

> You are doing something unorthodox. Is there a good reason for it? If
>   not, it might be better to stick to the basics.

Comment: I know it's all personally preference. But personally I find a mass of if statements far messier.

Comment: But that's the whole point of JSLint.  It advises you not just of illegal code, but also of poor coding practices.  And this "reversed switch" is a great example of "clever" code (*i.e.*, code that future changes will probably break, and which isn't particularly readable).

Answer (score 1):

```
numberOfColumns = Math.max(4, Math.floor(menuLinksLength / 3));
```

This will give you identical results to your existing code. Your question is fairly ambiguous, as "acceptable" is a very subjective term. I would personally reject any merge request with a reversed switch statement, because I actually can't think of a situation where that couldn't be replaced with something simpler and/or easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not a "reverse switch" is considered good practice in javascript depends on the specific use case.

In general, a reverse switch can make the code more readable and maintainable by clearly defining the intended behaviour for cases that don't match a specific pattern. This can be useful in situations where you want to catch all edge cases or exceptions that are not explicitly defined in the switch statement.