# Switch Statement with range value

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm writing swtich javascript switch statement in JS file and figured out the problem whole day still cannot find the solution.

Here is my javascript file written in jQuery :

```
var percent = 20;
var widthbytes;
switch(percent)
{
case 0:
   widthbytes=0;
   break;
    case (percent > 10 && percent < 20):
   widthbytes=16;
   break;
    case (percent >=20 && percent < 30):
       widthbytes=30;
       break;
default:
       widthbytes=0;
       break;
}
average.width(widthbytes);
```

It always return to default instead of 30. Anything wrong with my codes ?

Comment: This is not going to work. Use a simple if-else expression instead.

Comment: You can't write it like that. Either use `if`/`else` or a [reversed switch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658601/is-a-reversed-switch-statement-acceptable-javascript), although I wouldn't recommend the latter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

switch statements don't work like that. Your second case is checked like this: `if (percent == (percent > 10 && percent < 20)) ...`, which will not yield the desired result.

You could use an if / elseif / else construct:

```
if (percent === 0) {
  widthbytes = 0;
} else if (percent > 10 && percent < 20 {
  widthbytes = 16;
} else if (percent >= 20 && percent < 30 {
  widthbytes = 30;
} else {
  widthbytes = 0;
}
```

Or you could use a function that turns the ranges into constants:

```
function getRange(percent) {
  return Math.floor(percent/10);
}

switch(getRange(percent)) {
  case 10:
    widthbytes = 16;
    break;
  case 20:
    widthbytes = 30;
    break;
  default: 
    widthbytes = 0;  
}
```

Note that to get a cleaner implementation i assimilated your original case 0: into the default, since they both do the same thing. If that is not desirable, you need to change the getRange function to no longer return the same range for 0 as for any number between 0 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

switch statement only check the value of variable and then give the result according to that value so your expression

```
case (percent > 10 && percent < 20):
```

return boolean value which is not not comparable to variable value. Use if-else to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

just make a bit change in your code.
 You have **switch(percent)**in your code, only change for this ***switch(true)***.

The reason for that is because the switch statement return a boolean value, this is why we need they have the same comparation, i.e. boolean vrs boolean.

For example the ***case 10:*** return one value; true or false.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a problems with @Carlos Marin's answer. This works:-

```
var percent = 10; //test values-> 10, 11, 19, 20, 21, 29, 30
var widthbytes;

switch(true){
// case 0:
//    widthbytes=0;
//    break;
case (percent > 10 && percent < 20):
   widthbytes=16;
   break;
case (percent >=20 && percent < 30):
   widthbytes=30;
   break;
default:
   widthbytes=0;
   break;
}

console.log(widthbytes);
```