# How to disable the Weird Condition check in JSLint?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have some code that maps keyboard keys to blocks of code of varying length, from something as simple as `return false`, to mainly 2-3 line snippets, to complex functions:

```
var k = window.event.keycode;

switch(true){
    case(k === 9):
       //
    break;

    case(k === 13):
       //
    break;

    case(k === 38 && selectedRecord > 1):
       //
    break;
}
```

I'd rather not create an object with a list of functions and map it that way, because they're mainly short blocks of code and there is the odd complex `case`.

Is there an option to disable the check for `switch(true)` (as there are for other checks)?

Related, but not a duplicate: [Is a reversed switch statement acceptable JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658601/is-a-reversed-switch-statement-acceptable-javascript)

Comment: Why are you using `switch(true)` where a series of `if`/`else` blocks would be appropriate?

Comment: @EdCottrell That's a good question to be honest - legacy code.

Comment: Why don't you just do `switch(k) ..` and `case 9:`, `case 11:` and so on..?

Comment: @RahilWazir For odd cases like `case(k === 38 && selectedRecord > 1)`.

Comment: I'm going to change the `switch`es over to `if/else`s - there's one for each screen of this app, to map keys; fun task ahead! I'll leave this question here though, because there's probably an option to disable the check in JSLint.

Comment: @DannyBeckett You should nest the `selectedRecord > 1` within `if/else` statement under `case 38:`

Comment: @RahilWazir That actually makes more sense than `if/else`s.

Comment: @DannyBeckett True. I thought you are forcing yourself to use `switch` :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two thoughts:

1) You can make the linter happy by adding this comment at the top of the file: `/*jshint eqeqeq: true */` That said, I still get a `This 'switch' should be an 'if'.` warning. It may be that jslint/jshint just won't ignore this kind of construct.

2) Instead of turning of linter options, I would respectfully suggest that you take this opportunity to clean up rather strange code and rewrite your `switch` as follows:

```
var k = window.event.keycode;

if(k === 9) {
       //
} else if(k === 13) {
       //
} else if(k === 38 && selectedRecord > 1) {
       //
}
```

Comment: `/*jshint eqeqeq: true */` is presumably for JSHint, rather than JSLint, but otherwise good advice!

Comment: True, although I only got the "weird condition" warning from JSHint.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using the JSLint Notepad++ plugin; maybe something's awry with it. Thanks for your answer Ed!

Comment: Yeah, actually, that plugin is exactly how I just tested this. Anyway, glad to help!