# Disable weird condition check in jslint

Tags: javascript, jslint

I got some strange errors in my js library by **Jslint**.

```
if (d.r.test(this.user)) {
    return !0;
}
```

**Jslint Error**

Weird Condition

```
return !0;
```

I don't know what is wrong in the code, I used `return !0` instead of `return true` and I believe `return !0` will perform better than `return true`.

What is wrong in the code and how to disable the check in jslint?

P.S: [How to disable the Weird Condition check in JSLint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233814/how-to-disable-the-weird-condition-check-in-jslint)
I read this question before asking this but it is different and the solution suggested in that was not working.

Comment: What do you mean perform better?

Comment: Please check this out http://jsperf.com/bool-vs-int

Comment: Try to use jshint http://jshint.com/.

Comment: Ok it's maybe 1ms faster when you run it 20k times, but it's confusing to read which is probably why jslint is complaining about it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable the Weird Condition check in JSLint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233814/how-to-disable-the-weird-condition-check-in-jslint)

Comment: @jcubic I read the post before asking the question. It is different and the solution suggested on the question is not working.

Comment: As per me - it should not be marked duplicate as the solution suggested is for JSHint.

Comment: Just fwiw, here's [Atwood on "The Sad Tragedy of Micro-Optimization Theater" from 2009](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/). It's been one of my favorite reads. Which is to say, in this case, as [@bhspencer says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29825011/1028230), readable code >>> any gains here. ;^)

Comment: @kannanrbk I apologize for the misinformation I initially gave in my answer. I have corrected the answer to reflect the fact that this behavior cannot be disabled.

Comment: @Shubh I am using jslint not jshint.

Comment: Ohh!!! I got carried away while finding a hack that I mis-read hint as lint !! My bad... My Bad..  :) Removed the comment.

Comment: *lol* at "perform better" being a good reason for this code in this case. First of all, the jsperf you reference is doing something different, flipping a boolean vs. subtracting ints: your code needs to only return an *immediate value*. Second of all, flipping a value is an operation, a boolean isn't (ignoring optimizations), e.g., http://jsperf.com/true-vs-not0 (guess which performs better? Not an operation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a "Weird Condition" warning because your code is not idiomatic. Other programmers will likely find it confusing and so JSLint is warning you not to do it.

One of the intended goals of JSLint is to discourage problematic styles of programming. i.e. Just because you can do something in JavaScript doesn't mean it is a good idea. This is an example of one of those cases where the authors of JSLint believe this style of programming should be discouraged.

There is no way to turn off this warning in JSLint. I tried it here http://www.jslint.com/ and turned on all the tolerate options and still get the warning. The only way to prevent the warning is to either change the return value to be a boolean or to stop using JSLint.

Comment: Thank you.

I tried the solution suggested in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233814/how-to-disable-the-weird-condition-check-in-jslint but it is not working.

Comment: `eqeqeq` is [a JS**H**int option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233814/how-to-disable-the-weird-condition-check-in-jslint#comment37428239_24234762), not [a JSLint one](http://jslint.com/#JSLINT_OPTIONS), if that helps. You've got to change that return value if you want JSLint to be happy (so I'd edit this answer to reflect that, fwiw).

Comment: Agreed I do not believe it is possible to turn off this warning with JSLint

Comment: Yep, `eqeq` is, but `eqeqeq` [is not in JSLint](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/master/jslint.js). ;^)

Comment: @bhspencer It is 34% faster. I don't think it is very tiny performance improvement.

Comment: When you perform a micro benchmark thousands of times it is 34% faster but how many times do you use this in your application? How much faster is you application using this over a boolean? Were you noticing a performance problem in your application and did changing this particular thing make a noticeable difference? I would be surprised if it made much difference in typical use cases.

Comment: @kannanrbk You should compare equivalent code at the *very* least, e.g., http://jsperf.com/true-vs-not0.

Comment: I removed my bit about premature optimization from my answer as, despite my opinions, I don't think it is directly relevant to the question.

Comment: @DaveNewton agreed. 

I saw similar kind of lines in Google Chrome Dev Tools, Firefox and other too. Why they are using it without any reason?

Comment: @kannanrbk Same reason you are? Cargo-cult programming? They don't care about readability? They hate the programmers that have to maintain their code? Don't know--you'd need to ask them.

Comment: I am curious if any believe the answer given above is incorrect or does not answer the question. I am happy to make changes in the spirit of providing a canonical answer if people have suggestions.

Comment: @bhspencer your answer is absolutely fine but i am looking for an alternative. I will wait some time.

Comment: @kannanrbk If you want to use JSLint, you have to change the return value. If you're dying to use that return value, you can either use JSHint (or another linter) or create your own fork of JSLint that ignores `!0` usage with (as an example) a `/*jslint microOpt:true */` option you've coded up. I think those are your only real options.