# case user.length < 4; console.log("nametoo short :("); break; Why doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, string-length

I'm working on switch statements and I've been trying to make this code right here work, but it doesn't seem to output the correct console.log case string.

```
var user = prompt("What is your name?").toLowerCase();
switch(user){
    case "luka":
    console.log("What a beautiful name, my name is exactly the same :) Hi Luka! :D");
    break;

    case user.length > 10:
    console.log("That's a long name!");
    break;

    case user.length < 4:
    console.log("Not to be rude or impolite to you in any way, but your name is kinda       short :( Not that it isn't cool or something :D");
    break;

}
```

I've tried putting paranthesis around the user like this (user).length < 4, but that doesn't work, nor some of my other tries. Does anybody know how to implement this correctly?

Comment: Why would you want to use a switch statement like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one possible workaround for using `switch` in the cases like yours:

```
var user = prompt("What is your name?").toLowerCase();
switch (true) {
    case (user === "luka"):
        console.log("What a beautiful name, my name is exactly the same :) Hi Luka! :D");
        break;

    case (user.length > 10):
        console.log("That's a long name!");
        break;

    case (user.length < 4):
        console.log("Not to be rude or impolite to you in any way, but your name is kinda       short :( Not that it isn't cool or something :D");
}
```

However I'd follow [@epascarello's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15274431/1249581) advice and use `if/else` blocks.

Comment: This does work, but it's more code than an `if - else` sequence would be :-)

Comment: Absolutely so. That's why no one uses such construction :)

Comment: This definitely works, but I am very curious in knowing why my way of doing doesn't work? Why do I have to swap out user with true instead of just keeping the user variable inside the switch statement's parenthesis? Do you maybe know why? :S

Comment: I'm learning, experimenting, trying out. Still very new to JavaScript, and I like testing out various stuff in different ways, so it doesn't matter to me if someone doesn't use such a construction.

Comment: @user2097217 The best answer for that was given by [Pointy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15274456/1249581). You can compare the description in his answer with my code and you will entirely understand the point.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use conditionals in a switch statement.

Use if/else if

```
var user = prompt("What is your name?").toLowerCase();
if (user==="luka") {
    console.log("What a beautiful name, my name is exactly the same :) Hi Luka! :D");
} else if (user.length > 10) {
    console.log("That's a long name!");
} else if (user.length < 4) {
    console.log("Not to be rude or impolite to you in any way, but your name is kinda       short :( Not that it isn't cool or something :D");
} else {
    console.log("in else");
}
```

Comment: Why not? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463833/expression-inside-switch-case-statement

Answer (score 2):

That's just not how JavaScript `switch` statements work. The values in the "case" expressions are compared to the value of the `switch` expression.

The statement you have there is equivalent to:

```
if (user === "luka") {
    console.log("What a beautiful name, my name is exactly the same :) Hi Luka! :D");
}
else if (user === (user.length > 10)) {
    console.log("That's a long name!");
}
else if (user === (user.length < 4)) {
    console.log("Not to be rude or impolite to you in any way, but your name is kinda       short :( Not that it isn't cool or something :D");    
}
```

Thus, you're comparing the value of "user" to the *results* of comparing `user.length` to those values. Those comparison results are boolean, so "use" will *never* be `===` to them.

Comment: @user2097217 you have to use `if`; that's just not how `switch` statements work. See my expanded explanation.

Comment: but again, if user === user.length > 10 which then becomes true is should console.log("Thestringhere");

Comment: @user2097217 The code in this answer is NOT the solution. It is showing you EXACTLY what is happening in your code.

Comment: No, that's equivalent to `user === (true)` or `user === (false)`, which will never be `true` because a string is never `===` to a boolean.

Comment: I do not understand...
else if (user === (user.length > 10)) {
    console.log("That's a long name!");
} 
To me this means if user.length > 10 is true then user === true which then results in the console.log action. Isn't this right and why?

Comment: It's not right. The variable "user" has a value that's a **string**.  The comparison involving the string length is done first, and the result will be either `true` or `false`.  Those values are **boolean** values.  A string is **never** `===` to a boolean value, so that `===` comparison will never be true.