# My Date() JavaScript function is not working?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add text to my site based on the time. However, I cannot get it to work!

HTML:

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<script link="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
    <img id="bannerImage" src="banner.jpg" align="middle"></img>
</div id="header">
<section id="master">

<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="navObject">About Me</li>
        <li class="navObject">Products</li>
        <li class="navObject">Contact</li>  
        <li class="navObject">FAQ</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
<h3 id="welcomeText"></h3>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
 var timeAdd = function(){
                        var today = new Date();
                        var todayHour = today.getHours();
                        var message;

                        switch(todayHour){
                            case(todayHour > 18):
                                message = "Good Evening!";
                                break;
                            case(todayHour > 12):
                                message = "Good Afternoon!";
                                break;
                            case(todayHour > 0):
                                message = "Good Morning!";
                                break;
                            default:
                                message = "Welcome!";
                                break;
                            }
                            return message;
                            };
var tag = document.getElementById("welcomeText");
tag.textContent(timeAdd());
```

I just want to be able to add the message to said div. When I try the page, nothing comes up. I have tried different ways, so, what am I missing?

Comment: `tag.innerHTML = timeAdd()` should work.

Comment: You want to use `switch(true)`

Comment: @Antiga See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3463944/338803

Comment: @ColbyCox Before you post a question about JavaScript, try using Developer Tools console in your browser. In this case, it would have told you that the `textContent` property is not a function.

Comment: @vp_arth I didn't say that didn't evaluate to a boolean. In any case, no interest in arguing, you are missing what I'm saying. You can link that question all you want, I will still disagree with hacking up a case-switch to serve a purpose it wasn't intended to.

Comment: @ColbyCox You will also need to move your <script link="index.js"></script> tag before </body> since your JavaScript will be executed before the DOM is loaded. Also, <script src="index.js"></script> instead of <script link="..."></script>

Comment: @Antiga, `switch` is just `compare this value with followed and execute first matched code block`

Comment: @vp_arth I know what a switch statement is. Passing true to one to fib it is not what they're to be used for. That's what an if-else is for. You can even make your own comparison construct.

Comment: @Antiga, what useful in this holywar here? I found `if elseif elseif else` bedsheet ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment is wrong - it should be done in the following way:

```
tag.textContent = timeAdd();
```

better support however has `innerHTML`. You can use it the same way like `textContent`.

```
tag.innerHTML = timeAdd();
```

Also, you switch does not work. You have to use `switch(true)`, in order for it to work properly. Personally, I'd rather go with an `if else` which looks cleaner to me:

```
if (todayHour > 18){
   message = "Good Evening!";
} else if (todayHour > 12){
   message = "Good Afternoon!";
} else if (todayHour > 0){
   message = "Good Morning!";
} else {
   message = "Welcome!";
}
```

EDIT: Also, you have to care for the order of your script execution. Generally, you can include your `index.js` in the head, however this part:

```
var tag = document.getElementById("welcomeText");
tag.textContent =timeAdd();
```

**has to be executed after** you introduce `<h3 id="welcomeText"></h3>` in your markup. So either you call `index.js` after that element, or execute just these two lines afterwards:

```
<h3 id="welcomeText"></h3>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="index.js"></script> <!-- without the last two lines! -->
<h3 id="welcomeText"></h3>
<script>
    var tag = document.getElementById("welcomeText");
    tag.textContent =timeAdd();
</script>
```

Comment: @ColbyCox If all your problems are settled now you can mark your questions as solved to the SO community by accepting an answer as solution be ticking the checkmark right below the score.

Answer (score 0):

Instead set the `innerHtml` property, `text` or `html`

```
tag.innerHTML = timeAdd()
```

Comment: where do you have that info from? Sure an `h3` has the textContent property.

Comment: So you should remove your answer then?

Answer (score 0):

`textContent` is a property, not a method.
Also if you use boolean cases to match first you should use `true` as switch argument

Try this:

```
var timeAdd = function(){
  var today = new Date();
  var todayHour = today.getHours();
  var message;
  switch(true){
    case(todayHour > 18):
      message = "Good Evening!";
      break;
    case(todayHour > 12):
      message = "Good Afternoon!";
      break;
    case(todayHour > 0):
      message = "Good Morning!";
      break;
    default:
      message = "Welcome!";
      break;
  }
  return message;
};

var tag = document.getElementById("welcomeText");
tag.textContent = timeAdd();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here. First, remove the `id="header"` from the closing div tag; that is invalid HTML.

Second, the switch statement is not working the way you think it is. Use this as your timeAdd function instead (that name doesn't make sense either, maybe `getTimeGreeting` instead:

```
var timeAdd = function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var todayHour = today.getHours();
    var message = 'Welcome!';

    if (todayHour >= 18) {
        message = 'Good Evening!';
    } else if (todayHour >= 12) {
        message = 'Good Afternoon!';
    } else if (todayHour >= 0) {
        message = 'Good Morning!';
    }

    return message;
};
```

Finally, change the setting line to `tag.innerText = timeAdd();`