# Javascript Switch Range

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I recently started table top gaming and I don't want to deal with the calculations manually. Additionally, most of the apps have some kind of issue at any given time. I just began writing the basic javascript and can't seem to get the switch to work with the range. It reverts back to default. My code is below later on I will be putting the various modifiers/attributes into an array but I want the basic code to work first.

```
    <script>
var strMod=0;
var strength = prompt("what is your strength?");


switch(strength){
    case (strength>=0 && strength<2):
        strMod=-5;
        break;
    case (strength>=2 && strength<4):
        strMod=-4;
        break;
    case (strength>=4 && strength<6):
        strMod=-3;
        break;
    case (strength>=6 && strength<8):
        strMod=-2;
        break;
    case (strength>=8 && strength<10):
        strMod=-1;
        break;
    case (strength>=10 && strength<12):
        strMod=0;
        break;
    case (strength>=12 && strength<14):
        strMod=1;
        break;
    case (strength>=14 && strength<16):
        strMod=2;
        break;
    case (strength>=16 && strength<18):
        strMod=3;
        break;
    case (strength>=18 && strength<20):
        strMod=4;
        break;
    case (strength>=20 && strength<22):
        strMod=5;
        break;
    default:
        strMod= prompt("what is your strength modifier?");
        break;
}
console.log(strMod);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `switch(strength)` to `switch(true)`. This should work since you are comparing the results of the case statements to the value `true`, not to the value of `strength`.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eusw15g9/

See this accepted answer for more info: [Expression inside switch case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463833/expression-inside-switch-case-statement)

Comment: good call on the "overloaded" switch to evaluate multiple expressions. it's fast, simple to implement for the OP and does exactly what it says.

Comment: Great thinking -- I totally overlooked that (upvoted you) :)

Comment: I tried to use true before it didn't work, what could I have been doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks @dandavis and @Cymen! @eric-s - not sure, but check out the JSFiddle I linked to. It's the same exact thing as your code except the switch was changed as described above and the `console.log()` was changed to an `alert()`.

Comment: The JSFiddle worked great! Thanks @Nick Tiberi

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to use `switch-case`? Why don't you just do something like this:

```js
var strength = prompt("What is your strength?");
var strMod = Math.floor(strength / 2) -5;

document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = strMod;
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: I'm still relatively new to Javascript I'll look into the Math.floor script. that may be simple

Comment: `Math.floor` essentially means round down (for positive numbers). For example, `Math.floor(1.9) = 1` and `Math.floor(3.4)=3`

Comment: I see and I tried it out. it works great Thanks for the advise!

Comment: Lol great minds think alike `var strMod = Math.floor((str.value / 2) - 5);` I'll del my answer and up your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A switch does not work like that -- what you pass to `switch` is compared via equality to all of the case values. If there is a match, the case is selected otherwise the `default` happens (if one is defined).

You can either switch to a long `if () {} else if () {} ... else {}` chain or write a function that converts the range to a numerical value and switch on that value.

The function isn't even necessary in your case:

```
switch(Math.ceil(strength/2)){
    case 1:
        strMod=-5;
        break;
    case 2:
        strMod=-4;
        break;
    case 3:
        strMod=-3;
        break;
    case 4:
        strMod=-2;
        break;
    ...
```

And then simply guard for `<= 0` or `>= MAX` with an `if` before the switch.

Answer (score 0):

A switch statement evaluates expressions using **strict comparison** `===`. This means that the *input* expression will be === compare with first case clause matching in your switch. Therefore in your example above it will turn out to be `default` statement

Comment: oh... I read somewhere that you could use a range, but since I can't maybe if statements would be better?

Comment: There are various ways to achieve what you need and if statement is one of them