# How to match a template string in switch statement with js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, switch-statement, template-strings

I have a function that returns a component that depends on the pathname of the window.

```
getComponentByPathname = (pathname) => {
    switch(patname){
      case "/view1": return <ViewOneComponent>;
      case "/view2": return <ViewTwoComponent>;
}
```

But the problem starts when I try to evaluate a template string that has one id

```
getComponentByPathname = (pathname) => {
    switch(pathname){
      case "/view1": return <ViewOneComponent>;
      case "/view2": return <ViewTwoComponent>;
      case `/view3/${getId()}`: return <ViewThreeComponent>;

}
```

It's only working with the first two cases. Why?
Also, I make another attempt. In this case, I literally paste the string with the Id in the third case, like this:

```
case "view3/1234567": return <ViewThreeComponent>;
```

And works. But the problem is that I can not hardcode the id in the string.

How  I can evaluate that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expression inside switch case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463833/expression-inside-switch-case-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that getId() is returning a different value then what you expect. I would try the following and make that getId() is returning the expected value when it is being calculated

```
getComponentByPathname = pathname => {
  const case3 = `/view3/${getId()}`;
  console.log(`case3 = ${case3}`);
  console.log(`pathname = ${pathname}`);

  switch (pathname) {
    case '/view1':
      return <ViewOneComponent>;
    case '/view2':
      return <ViewTwoComponent>;
    case case3:
      return <ViewThreeComponent>;
  }
};
```

But if you only need to decide which component to render based on your path then something like this might be more appropriate

```js
const examplePaths = ['view1/', 'view2/', 'view3/', 'view3/1241232', 'view3/8721873216', 'view4/', 'vi/ew1', ''];

const mapper = {
  view1: 'ViewOneComponent',
  view2: 'ViewTwoComponent',
  view3: 'ViewThreeComponent'
};

examplePaths.forEach(ent => {
  const splitPaths = ent.split('/');

  const mapped = mapper[splitPaths[0]];
  if (mapped) {
    console.log(mapped);
  } else {
    console.log('Path not supported');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine here

```js
function getId() {
  return 1234567
}

function test(pathname) {
  switch (pathname) {
    case '/view1':
      return 'ViewOneComponent'
    case '/view2':
      return 'ViewTwoComponent'
    case `/view3/${getId()}`:
      return 'ViewThreeComponent'
    default:
      return 'fail'
  }
}

console.log(test('/view3/1234567'))
```