# useEffect only fires at first render when I use a switch statement

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can someone please explain why the following first example renders only once at the start, but the second works as expected and renders when the window is resized to be smaller/larger than 650px:

Doesn't work:

```
function useWindowResize() {
  const [width, setWindowWidth] = useState(getWindowSize(window.innerWidth))
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => setWindowWidth(getWindowSize(window.innerWidth))
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    }
  }, )
  return width
}

function getWindowSize(size) {
  switch (size) {
    case (size >= 650):
      return 'lrg'
    default:
      return 'sml'
  }
}
```

Works:

```
function useWindowResize() {
  const [width, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth < 650 ? true : false)
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth < 650 ? true : false)
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    }
  }, )
  return width
}
```

Some component file:

```
export default () => {
 const width = useWindowResize()  
 console.log(width) //Second example updates first doesn't
  return(...)
}
```

Comment: why you don't add `getWindowSize` inside `useEffect` ?

Comment: @Vencovsky this is unnecessary as the function is defined outside of the component and guaranteed to never change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expression inside switch case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463833/expression-inside-switch-case-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You switch case always returns 'sml' because you cannot add size as comparison to the switch and have an if within the case. Write it like this:

```
function getWindowSize(size) {
  switch (true) {
    case (size >= 650):
      return 'lrg'
    default:
      return 'sml'
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah i didn't know you can do that with `true` but why it doesn't work with switch (size) ?

Comment: Because it compares size with size >= 650 and number(size) === size>=650(boolean) is always false. If you set the switch to true, it only uses the seconds case condition.

Comment: Make sense, Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Regarding the execution, it should be exactly the same. Can you verify that you really use the posted code?

Answer (score 2):

`switch` is not like an `if` statement or a `ternary` expression, you can't evaluate an expression inside a `case` so `getWindowSize` always returns 'sml' as default

Simply change `getWindowSize` to use `if` statements or a `ternary`

```
function getWindowSize(size) {
  return size >= 650 ? 'lrg' : 'sml';
}
```