# Why this switch statement is ignoring cases and always applies the default?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can anyone please explain why this switch statement always jumps to default even though other cases are true?

```
const formatDays = (days) => {
  const d = Number(days);
  console.log(d, d === 1, d > 1 && d <= 4)
  switch (d) {
    case d === 1:
      return `${days} den`;
    case d > 1 && d <= 4:
      return `${days} dny`;
    default:
      return `${days} dní`;
  }
};

// Console output
> formatDays(1)
> 1 true false
> "1 dní"
> formatDays(4)
> 4 false true
> "4 dní"
> formatDays(10)
> 10 false false
> "10 dní"
```

Comment: `d !== (d === 1)`, for example.

Comment: The switch compares the value to the case. The case itself is not a true/false condition.

Comment: You need to read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+range+conditions+in+switch+case) of [Expression inside switch case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3463833/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I understand. In my case I need to match only full numbers so this would do the work:

```
const formatDays = (days) => {
  const d = Number(days);
  console.log(d, d === 1, d > 1 && d <= 4)
  switch (d) {
    case 1:
      return `${days} den`;
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
      return `${days} dny`;
    default:
      return `${days} dní`;
  }
};
```

If I needed intervals then something like this would solve the same problem:

```
const formatDays = (days) => {
  const d = Number(days);
  console.log(d, d === 1, d > 1 && d <= 4)
  if (d === 1) {
    return `${days} den`;
  } else if (d > 1 && d <= 4) {
    return `${days} dny`;
  } else {
    return `${days} dní`;
  }
};
```

And if you still want to use switch statement there is also a [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463833/expression-inside-switch-case-statement) with `true`:

```
const formatDays = (days) => {
  const d = Number(days);
  console.log(d, d === 1, d > 1 && d <= 4)
  switch (true) {
    case d === 1:
      return `${days} den`;
    case d > 1 && d <= 4:
      return `${days} dny`;
    default:
      return `${days} dní`;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Because that's not [how switch works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). It's not an if/else construct.

> …matching the expression's value to a case clause…

```js
switch (d) {
```

Looks for a case that *matches the value of `d`* and all of your cases evaluate to a boolean value.

Consider a scenario where `d` is `1`. You're effectively doing this:

```js
switch (d) {
 // d === 1 evaluates to true;
 // d !== true, so this gets skipped.
 case true:
    return `${days} den`;
}
```

A simple alternative would be an if/else chain. When you have more conditions (or more complicated ones), I prefer a predicate pattern, where you define an array of handlers. Each item declares a predicate function that returns true or false indicating whether it can handle the given value. You find the first one that returns true and invoke its format function:

```js
const formats = [
  {
    handles: value => value === 1,
    format: days => `${days} den`,
  },
  {
    handles: value => value > 1 && value <= 4,
    format: days => `${days} dny`,
  },
  {
    handles: value => true, // default, handles anything else
    format: days => `${days} dní`,
  },
]

const formatDays = days => (
  formats
    .find(f => f.handles(days)) // find a formatter that handles this value
    .format(days) // and invoke its format function
);

console.log(formatDays(1)); // 1 den
console.log(formatDays(5)); // 5 dny
console.log(formatDays(12)); // 12 dní
```

Comment: So what's your suggestion to fix this please?

Comment: Use an `if else` statement instead of a switch. As mentioned above a switch is for comparing against a value, not for evaluating an expression