# Is there any performance gain from using a switch statement over a bunch of if()else if() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, switch-statement, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript switch vs. if…else if…else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922948/javascript-switch-vs-if-else-if-else)

just curious if things will run faster or be laid out in cache nicer or something that might increase performance by using a switch? At very least I know it looks nice and allows the next code to see that all the next sequential statements are dependent upon the evaluation of the same variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, `switch` is faster than `if - else if` statements.

However, kind of best practice is to use `if - else if` if you got max 3 conditionals. If you're going beyond that, you should use `switch` statements.

The problem with `if else` is that it possibly needs to check multiple times before it finally reaches the code to execute. Therefore you also need to optimize the order for your conditional statements.

```
if( foo ) {
}
else if( bar ) {
}
else if( baz ) {
}
```

That code would not make much sense from a performance prospective if you expect `baz` to be `true` and `foo`/`bar` to be `false` most of the times.

Comment: Thank you for this sanity check!