# How to optimize nested if?

Tags: javascript

Hi I want to know is there a better way to do this? condition_a is more important than b, b is more important than c, etc.

```js
var slot = condition_a

if (!slot) {
  slot = condition_b
  if (!slot) {
    slot = condition_c
    if (!slot) {
      slot = condition_d
      if (!slot) {
        slot = condition_e
      }
    }
  }
}

if (slot) {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: There is no better way for this. whatever you did is correct way.

Comment: No, I am 25. Just learning a hobby.

Comment: @JaydipJadhav - there's 3 answers that are far more succinct, and, if you know javascript, are far more readable to even an intermediate level coder

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922948/javascript-switch-vs-if-else-if-else?  The linked article on that question has a rather good (but possibly outdated) breakdown of conditional performance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you need `slot` to have a value (and not just using it to test the condition at the end)

```
var slot = condition_a || condition_b || condition_c || condition_d || condition_e;
if (slot) {
  // do soemthing
}
```

Comment: Didn't you see the previous identical answer ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret - no, please show me a previous **identical** answer for your chance to win big prizes

Comment: @Jaromanda X Yes thanks this is the exact way I do it. var slot = (a || b || c); if(slot) { slot.dosomething() };

Answer (score 3):

You do a [OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()):

```
if (condition_a || condition_b || condition_c || condition_d || condition_e) {
      // do something
}
```

This is equivalent to your code. If a condition evaluates to `true`, the following ones aren't checked (it's called [*short circuit evaluation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation)). It makes it possible to have checks like this:

```
if (a===null || a.b===0) {
```

Be careful that so many conditions at the same place look like a code smell: there's probably something which hasn't be designed semantically enough.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote, this seems to be a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but I think he wants `if (!condition_a || !condition_b || ... !condition_e)`

Comment: @JaromandaX read OP again, he is checking negative of `slot` not `slot` itself.

Comment: @gurvinder372 - brush up on your logic

Comment: @gurvinder372 He is checking negative of slot just to see if another condition needs to be checked

Comment: @gurvinder372 but the logic quiz results in that solution ;)

Comment: DenysSéguret, agreed my bad +1 for the good logic. @Jaromand-x perhaps you can brush up your articulation skills. An explanation would have suffice than saying `wrong`!!

Comment: @gurvinder372 he just gave you the change to solve the quiz yourself

Comment: @gurvinder372 - why? you didn't ask the question. You merely added what you "think" the OP wanted, you added nothing to this answer except confusion - anything more than `wrong` would appear as if I cared

Comment: @Denys Séguret Sorry but that doesn't work, I should have made it more clear in my question. The condition_ are different actions, so the //do something part will be different base on the slot. I want to check if condition_a is true, if true do something immediately. If failed then check condition_b if true do something immediately

Comment: @lock This is exactly what's achieved. The second part of the || is only executed when the first part is falsy.

Comment: @Denys Séguret I just test it and it worked! This is so much more convenient.

Comment: @lock - how can this possibly work since you don't know WHICH condition's function to use?

Comment: @Jaromanda X I am using your variation. By worked I mean the Short-Circuit Evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `||` condition like this also,

```
slot = condition_a||condition_b||condition_c||condition_d;
```

Example [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tc2cdys/)