# When and why should I opt for a Switch Statement over a Chaining If Else Statements?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, chaining

I'm practicing Javascript and I wrote the following code by using the ***Switch Statement*** (it runs correctly):

```js
function switchOfStuff(val) {
  var answer = "";
  switch (val) {
    case 'a':
      answer = 'apple';
      break;
    case 'b':
      answer = 'bird';
      break;
    case 'c':
      answer = 'cat';
      break;
    default:
      answer = 'stuff';
  }
  return answer;
}

console.log(switchOfStuff('a'));
```

By substituting the *Switch statement* with a ***chaining if else statement*** I get the same output (`"apple"`).

```js
function switchOfStuff(val) {
  if (val = 1) {
    return "apple";
  } else if (val = 2) {
    return "bird";
  } else if (val = 3) {
    return "cat";
  } else {
    return "stuff";
  }
  return answer;
}

console.log(switchOfStuff('a'));
```

Both the snippets require 13/14 lines of code and return the same output: is there any reason why I should opt for the Switch Statement over the Chaining If Else Statement (or viceversa) and under what circumstances?

Comment: A `switch` statement expresses intend better. You want to do something depending on the value of a single variable.  Generally speaking, the more specific the syntax, the clearer the intend, IMO. However, for this specific case, I'd just use an object of the form `{a: 'apple', b: 'bird'}` and do something like `return answers[val] || 'stuff'`.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/222153

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922948/javascript-switch-vs-if-else-if-else

Comment: Your `if` statements are all wrong. You need to use `==`, not `=`.

Comment: @Barmar the output I get is the same in this case. Is there any other circumstance where using '==' instead than '=' returns a different output?

Comment: There's no way it can produce the same output. It should always output `apple`. When you write `if (x = y)` it's essentially the same as writing `x = y; if (x)`

Comment: Your second snippet doesn't even make much sense. You're passing a letter to the function, but then testing it against a number.

Comment: Try passing `'b'` to both functions. The first will print `bird`, the second will print `apple` again.

Comment: It's just coincidence that you get the same answer in the two examples you gave. The functions will work differently with different inputs.