# Alternatives to a large if/switch with multiple cases in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have multiple if statements (50/60) inside a loop.What would be the best approach to perform this actions, switch or map lookup? How can i implement map lockups for the  following examples?

```
errors.forEach((e) => {
      if (e.field === 'firstName') {
        this.hasErrorFirstName = true;
        this.msgFirstName = e.error;
      }
      if (e.field === 'lastName') {
        this.hasErrorLastName = true;
        this.msgLastName = e.error;
      }
      if (e.field === 'middleName') {
        this.hasErrorMiddleName = true;
        this.msgMiddleName = e.error;
      }
      if (e.field === 'address') {
        this.hasErrorAddress = true;
        this.msgAddress = e.error;
      }
     }
```

Comment: Hi @user2410266, you can use switch statements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript switch vs. if...else if...else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922948/javascript-switch-vs-if-else-if-else)

Comment: Is switch the best options or I can use map lookups. https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/switch-case-if-else-or-a-lookup-map-a-study-case-de1c801d944

Comment: Map lookup is the way to go

Comment: How can I implement map lookups for multiple statements with my example.

Answer (score 3):

You can do some thing like below

```
const obj = {
  firstName: ['hasErrorFirstName', 'msgFirstName'],
  lastName: ['hasErrorLastName', 'msgLastName'],
}

errors.forEach(e => {
  if (Object.keys(obj).includes(e.field)) {
    const [has, msg] = obj[e.field];
    this[has] = true;
    this[msg] = e.error
  }
})
```

Comment: Looks like this is not a best practice to do as in this case also user have to write all the fields manually inside `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that data is stored in inefficient way. There may be no need to have separate `hasErrorFirstName` and `msgFirstName` keys, because error message can be forced to be truthy and be an indicator that there's an error. And there is no need to have keys that are named differently than respective fields. In this case an array can be mapped to a map of error messages:

```
Object.fromEntries(errors.map(e => [e.field, e.error]))
```