# Switch multiple case execution

Tags: javascript, java, switch-statement, case

I try to execute more than one case in `switch` statement. I wrote this as a `if` statement but I read somewhere is the `switch` is more efficient than `if`. Now execute always only first correct.

```
      let num = 30;
      switch (true) {
        case (num >= 20):
          console.log("code for case 1");
          break;
        case (num == 31) :
          console.log("code for case 2");
          break;
        case (num < 50):
          console.log("code for case 3");
          break;
        case (num == 10 + 20):
          console.log("code for case 4");
          break;
      }
```

Can I execute all true cases? or stay with many `if else`?

```
code for case 1
code for case 3
code for case 4
```

Comment: It's true that `switch` can be faster than `if-else`, but this is only relevant when the logic of the code is convertible between the two. Planes are faster than submarines, but sometimes you can't take a plane because of, well... complications.

Comment: @nullromo - *"It's true that switch can be faster than if-else,"* Not really in JavaScript, and certainly not ones like the above. JavaScript's `switch` is just `if`/`else if`/`else` with different syntax. `case` labels are expressions (not just literals) as you can see in the question, so the C-like optimizations (jump tables, etc.) aren't available. (If the `case` labels **were** literals, then maybe the JavaScript engine could do something with it, but...)

Comment: I see what you mean. I was going based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2923007/4476484). That's why I said "_can be_ faster."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch statements should normally be used when you want to choose one option. There is a "fallthrough" behavior, however.

```js
switch(x) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
        doSomething();
        // no break here!
    case 3:
        doOtherThing();
        break;
    case 4:
        // ...
}
```

In the above code, if `x` is 1 or 2, both `doSomething()` and `doOtherThing()` will happen, whereas if `x` is 3, then only `doOtherThing()` will happen.

If you want to do some more complex combination of operations with conditions, `if` statements are probably better.

Comment: I saw this solution on the website, it won't help me unfortunately, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

> Can I execute all true cases?

Not reasonably, no, and moreover it isn't the right tool for that job. Instead of `switch`, use a series of `if` statements:

```js
let num = 30;
if (num >= 20) {
    console.log("code for case 1");
}
if (num == 31)  {
    console.log("code for case 2");
}
if (num < 50) {
    console.log("code for case 3");
}
if (num == 10 + 20) {
    console.log("code for case 4");
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but wanted to make sure. but thanks for the code anyway

Answer (score 0):

Once you have left a case clause of a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) with `break`, you can not get into the switch statement again.

Not even a *fall through*, like a bundle of cases without `break` does not work for your problem to have multiple checks and the **same amount** of actions.

A solution is to use single check with `if` and go on with another `if`

```
if (condition1) console.log('condition 1');
if (condition2) console.log('condition 2');
// and so on
```